# Configuring Fairness Monitoring for categorical features

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-openscale

When configuring fairness monitoring for a model, the prediction column only allows for integer numerical value even though the prediction label are categorical, is this an intended feature? How do I configure this for categorical feature (that is not integer)? is a manual conversion required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The training data could have class labels such as “Loan Denied”, “Loan Granted”.  The prediction value returned by WML scoring end point has values such as “0.0”, “1.0", etc.  The scoring end point also has an optional column which contains the text representation of prediction. E.g., if prediction=1.0, the predictionLabel column could have a value “Loan Granted”.   If such a column is available, then while configuring the favourable and unfavourable outcome for the model, you can specify the string values “Loan Granted” and “Loan Denied”. If such a column is not available then you need to specify the integer/double values of 1.0, 0.0 for the favourable/unfavourable class.

WML has a concept of output schema which defines the schema of the output of WML scoring end point and the role for the different columns.  The roles are used to identify which column contains the prediction value, which column contains the prediction probability, and the class label value, etc.  The output schema is automatically set for models created using model builder.  It can also be set using the WML python client.  Users can use the output schema to define a column which contains the string representation of the prediction.  This is done by setting the modeling_role for the column to ‘decoded-target’.  The documentation for the WML python client is available at: http://wml-api-pyclient-dev.mybluemix.net/#repository.  Search for “OUTPUT_DATA_SCHEMA” to understand the output schema and the API to use is to store_model API which accepts the OUTPUT_DATA_SCHEMA as a parameter.